# SFDX deploy reporting subfolders

Tags: reporting, salesforcedx, metadata-api

I am trying to deploy some reports using sfdx. However when I perform the deployment the report folders all sit as top level report folders and my subfolders do not appear as expected.

My path is as follows:

`Reports/ - Contains Top Level Folder meta.xml and Top Level Folder`

`Reports/Top Level Folder - Contains Sub Folder meta.xml`

`Reports/Top Level Folder/SubFolder - Contains All the Report files`

[image]

Is there something wrong with this setup or something that I am missing?

Thanks in Advance for any help on this.

Comment: Try just going to metadata deploy using traditional source format as the new source format may have bugs

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: It seems that the new source format (YourReport.report-meta.xml instead of YourReport.report) won't support the deployment of reports or dashboards in a report/dashboard folder if that folder doesn't already exist in the org you're targeting. 

Whenever I try to do this, I always hit an 'Report Folder X doesn't exist' error in the SFDX CLI. 

So, you can of course either deploy this in the older meta-data format (YourReport.report) or you can create the report/dashboard folders manually in the target org and then deploy via the source format.

Comment: Having updated my sfdx version, I am now able to deploy this via sfdx. Perhaps try updating your sfdx cli version.